# Using functions to solve other functions (sinx, cosx, exp) in C

Tags: c, function, trigonometry, exp

my professor gave me a confusing problem and I'm completely lost on what to do. Basically he wants me to solve cos(x) and exp(x) (he gave an example for sinx) without using the built in math.h functions. Not only that, but he wants me to use both the fact() and power() functions to solve it. I could most likely solve it through straight math but I'm a bit lost on using the functions. I understand the general concept but I suck at math (especially trig) and I'm not exactly sure what they functions are doing arithmetically. Any helps or points to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char    more;
    double  x, mySin(), myCos(), myExp();


    printf("\n\n\t\tInput X: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

  do {
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tLibraryResult     MyResult");
    printf("\n\n\tsin< %5.2f>    %7.5f     %7.5f", x, sin(x), mySin(x));
    printf("\n\n\tcos< %5.2f>    %f     %f", x, cos(x), myCos(x));
    printf("\n\n\texp< %5.2f>    %f     %f", x, exp(x), myExp(x));
    printf("\n\n\t\tDo More (Y/N)? ");
    scanf("%s",&more);
  }
    while (more == 'y'||more == 'Y');
}
double power(double x, int n)
{
    int     i = 0;
    double  prod = 1.;

    for ( ; i++ < n; )
        prod = prod * x;

    return prod;
}
double fact (int n)
{
    int     i;
    double prod = 1.;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        prod = prod * i;

    return prod;
}
double mySin(double x)
{
    int     i, sign;
    double  sum = 0;

    for (i = 0, sign = 1; i < 21; i++, sign = -sign)
        sum = sum + sign * power(x, 2 * i + 1)/ fact(2 * i + 1);
    return sum;
}
double myCos(double x)
{


}
double myExp(double x)
{



}
```

Comment: Do you understand Taylor expansions? This may be more a computational math question than a programming question.

Comment: Ahhh so this is where he's getting his math from. This should help a lot lol. Thx

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but you can see here a maclaurin expansion for sine, which i believe what you have implemented http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/maclaurin-expansion-of-sinx/

Comment: I just solved it with Aschepler's help. I really just needed to know where my professor was getting his arithmetic. All this math is way over my head but i was able to understand it to some degree with my professors's example and googling Taylor expansions. Thanks though!